# How to bind NgbModalOptions size on click in html

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular-bootstrap

There's a button which calls bootstrap modal open(content) on html page. Requirement is to need to pass the size of the modal too ('sm','lg').
Using Angular 2 Bootstrap Modal. can anybody help me on this .

html :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-add" (click)="open(content)">Add</button>

<ng-template #Deletecontent let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Device</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body delete-modal">
        <p>Are sure you want to delete this device/devices?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-cancel" (click)="c('Close click')">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" (click)="deleteDevices()">Delete</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-class. Like..

```
[ngClass]="'style1'"
```

Use it in your div and apply condition on model open.

Answer (score 1):

In your function open

```
open(content: any) {
   this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' });
}
```